# $watch in post link of compile not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-compile, angularjs-watch

I am trying to apply `$watch` on a attribute in the post link function.

My code is like this :

```
compile: function(){
     return {
         post:function(scope,element){
             scope.$watch('scope.x', function(){
                console.log(scope.x);
            })  
         }
     }
}
```

It executes only once when the page is loaded. Is there anything wrong that I am unable to figure out?

Edit :

I am using angular gridster to show various charts in a grid. My index.html look like :

```
<div gridster>
    <ul>
        <chart ng-repeat="chart in charts">
        </chart>
   </ul>
</div>
```

chart is another directive with a view:

```
<li gridster-item row="grid_row" col="grid_col">
```

script file contains:

```
module.directive('chart', ['',
    function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                  grid_col: '=col',
                  grid_row: '=row',
            },
            compile: function(element, attrs) {
                return {
                     post: function(scope, element, timeout) {
                         scope.$watch('grid_col', function() {
                         console.log(scope.grid_col);
                       })
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't mention `scope` name in `string` provided to `$watch`.

```
scope.$watch('x', function(){
    console.log(scope.x);
})
```

`$watch` over scope will place inside $$watchers object inside `$scope` & evaluats each string value against scope on each digest loop.

Comment: I tried this, but to no avail, it works for the first time but nothing gets printed in the console after that.

Comment: @user3035998 could you provide me a plunkr?